# Nmap -Pn -Sn together give inaccurate results

Tags: nmap

When I run these two commands, I get the same conclusive (accurate) results that 44 host are up

```
sudo nmap -Pn 10.2.16.0/24
sudo nmap -sn 10.2.16.0/24
```

When I run a scan with both of these commands together, I get an inaccurate result that 256 hosts are up

```
sudo nmap -Pn 10.2.16.0/24
```

From the googling that I've done I guess what's happening is that nmap is assuming all 256 hosts are up and it's attempting a reverse DNS resolution of the host, which attempts to enumerate the name of the host.  What I don't get is why it assumes all 256 hosts are up when -Pn and -sn are run together, but not by themselves.

Also, I am not receiving host names of any of the devices with either of these scans.  I just get the IP Address, MAC Address and Manufacture Name.  Is that due to my resolv.conf file?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get inaccurate results is because running `nmap -Pn -sn` doesn't make any sense.

`-Pn` tells nmap to treat every host as up, and `-sn` tells nmap to skip the port scan and just tell whether a host is up.

So in combination you say "Tell me if a host is up. Also, every host is to be treated as if it is up." and nmap obliges, telling you "All hosts are up".

---

When you run just `-sn`, it will run a ping scan and report that 44 hosts are up. Whether or not that is correct is unknown. There might be 50 hosts up, but 6 are configured not to respond to pings. But it *looks* like a sensible answer.

When you run just `-Pn` nmap will tell you that all hosts are up, but many have no open ports at all. This is because nmap can't differentiate between a host, that is down, and a host that is just not answering to you.

---

As for your hostnames: This depends on whether the DNS server allows reverse resolution. Usually, DNS works by querying for a host name and receiving an IP address. A reverse query queries for an IP address and asks for the associated hostname.

Some DNS servers disable this feature, so if it doesn't work for you, then that DNS is likely configured not to allow reverse queries